# Python 3.6 - pass a variable inside a string command

Tags: python, variables, object, reference, byte

In Python 3.6 I am trying to reference a variable from outside to inside a byte object.

This is a section of my code that I have simplified to try and explain the point.

```
#set my variable here
RECORDID = 'MyRecordID'

#create a byte object where the RECORDID needs to be passed to
output_buffer1 = b"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><AMS<TransportControl><RecordCue ID=RECORDID /></TransportControl></AMS>"
```

My byte object is an essentially an XML string that I am passing to an external API, but I need to be able to put the RECORDID inside that XML string at this position

```
<RecordCue ID= here />
```

so that the result is

```
<RecordCue ID='MyRecordID' />
```

Basically, how do I reference that variable from within the byte object?  I have tried putting a percent sign and a plus sign, brackets etc around the variable name but it wont work.  It always outputs exactly what I type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `str()`?

Comment: yes i have.  anything i type inside quotes after the b gets taken literally as its typed.

Comment: Since you're on Python 3.6 you could also use the f-strings: `f"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><AMS<TransportControl><RecordCue ID={RECORDID} /></TransportControl></AMS>".encode('utf-8')`. I was expecting `fb"somestring"` or  `bf"somestring"` to work as well, but it is not seem to be working. o_O

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your suggestion, ive tried changing to an f string as you suggest, but no joy.  Frustrating!

Comment: Have a look at concatenation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: For a more advanced approach, have a look at Format Strings https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: solved by splitting the string into parts and concatenating around the variables.  Thanks all